# Which field in Apache Bench is the Response-Time?

Tags: apachebench

I try to interpret the fields of apache bench, but I can't understand which field is that indicates the Response-time . Can you help me find that?

```
Document Path:          /
Document Length:        45563 bytes

Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   3.955 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      4625489 bytes
HTML transferred:       4556300 bytes
Requests per second:    25.29 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       79.094 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       39.547 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1142.21 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       40   53   8.1     51      99
Processing:    12   24   9.4     23      98
Waiting:        5   14  10.6     12      95
Total:         57   77  15.0     75     197

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     75
  66%     77
  75%     80
  80%     81
  90%     85
  95%     92
  98%    116
  99%    197
 100%    197 (longest request)
```

Comment: There isn't one, because it fires off **multiple** requests in parallel. What singlar, scalar "response time" are you after, exactly? If you want an average, then use `Time per request: X (mean, across all concurrent requests)`.

Comment: @Dai Yes , I want the average Response-Time. Thank You.